# Parsing JSON into Java Objects

Tags: java, json

I have a complex nested JSON response. I want to parse the whole JSON. I tried object mapper from Jackson and used automatically generated POJO classes from http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ . But objectmapper is unable to map the JSON into java object.
For instance , I want to access coordinates.

```
    {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "Feature": {
        "name": "info",
        "request-id": 18,
        "computing-time (ms)": 44,
        "number-of-points": 31,
        "message": "Routing was successful, number of Points 31",
        "description": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "startingpoint",
        "_umap_options": {
          "color": "DarkGreen"
        }
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          84.00761988067208,
          28.213982682943577
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "destination",
        "_umap_options": {
          "color": "DarkRed"
        }
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          84.00688545421255,
          28.21633003390573
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Route",
        "_umap_options": {
          "opacity": "1"
        }
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            84.00761988067208,
            28.213982682943577
          ],

          [
            84.00683181003106,
            28.21585748082081
          ],
          [
            84.00685453430238,
            28.21587163692426
          ],
          [
            84.00686123982507,
            28.21589994913116
          ],

          [
            84.00666156426061,
            28.216708150879477
          ],
          [
            84.00672861948748,
            28.216617253794162
          ],
          [
            84.00688545421255,
            28.21633003390573
          ]
        ]
      },
      "details": {
        "distance": [
          [
            0,
            3,
            70.82049008282796
          ],
          [
            3,
            5,
            106.922
          ],
          [
            5,
            7,
            42.881
          ],
          [
            7,
            9,
            46.08
          ],
          [
            9,
            30,
            378.041
          ]
        ]
      },
      "instructions": [
        {
          "distance": 70.82,
          "heading": 51.99,
          "sign": 0,
          "interval": [
            0,
            3
          ],
          "text": "Continue",
          "time": 50990,
          "street_name": ""
        },
        {
          "distance": 106.922,
          "sign": -2,
          "interval": [
            3,
            5
          ],
          "text": "Turn left onto Gaudako Mukh",
          "time": 76983,
          "street_name": "Gaudako Mukh"
        },
        {
          "distance": 42.881,
          "sign": 2,
          "interval": [
            5,
            7
          ],
          "text": "Turn right",
          "time": 30874,
          "street_name": ""
        },
        {
          "distance": 424.121,
          "sign": 7,
          "interval": [
            7,
            30
          ],
          "text": "Keep right onto Way to Matepani Monastry",
          "time": 305366,
          "street_name": "Way to Matepani Monastry"
        },
        {
          "distance": 0,
          "sign": 4,
          "last_heading": 154.303263806682,
          "interval": [
            30,
            30
          ],
          "text": "Arrive at destination",
          "time": 0,
          "street_name": ""
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "_umap_options": {
          "color": "DarkSlateGrey",
          "fillOpacity": "0.2",
          "fillColor": "Chocolate",
          "opacity": "0.5"
        },
        "name": "barrierrange"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              83.99725424061455,
              28.22419972596586
            ]

          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my mapping code.

```
package com.pojotest.jsonreader.controller;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.pojotest.jsonreader.model.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class Api
{

    @PostMapping(value = "/feed")
    public Object returnData(@RequestBody ReadResponse a) throws JsonProcessingException
    {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        JsonNode jsonNode = a.getResponse();
        try {
            JsonNode features = jsonNode.get("features");

            String Feature = features.toPrettyString(); //requets string

            System.out.println(getFeature(Feature));



            Feature featureObj = objectMapper.readValue(getFeature(Feature), Feature.class);
            RefinedResponse refinedResponse = new RefinedResponse(a.getTimeStamp(), a.getRequest(), featureObj);


            return refinedResponse;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            RefinedResponse refinedResponse = new RefinedResponse();
            refinedResponse.setRequest(a.getRequest());
            refinedResponse.setTimeStamp(a.getTimeStamp());
            return refinedResponse;
        }

    }


   public String getFeature(String wholeString)
   {
       int  firstIndex = wholeString.indexOf("\"Feature\" : ") + (new String("\"Feature\" : ").length());
       int lastIndex = wholeString.indexOf('}') + 1;
       return wholeString.substring(firstIndex,lastIndex);
   }
}
```

I want to parse this whole JSON into Java object. But It gives this warning and no parsing is done.

```
 2020-06-18 15:24:21.475  WARN 21930 --- [nio-7777-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.Float` out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.Float` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 60, column: 13] (through reference chain: com.pojotest.jsonreader.fullmodel.Fullresponse["response"]->com.pojotest.jsonreader.fullmodel.Response["features"]->java.util.ArrayList[3]->com.pojotest.jsonreader.fullmodel.Feature["geometry"]->com.pojotest.jsonreader.fullmodel.Geometry["coordinates"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])]
```

My whole project is available here
https://filebin.net/xk7qldtqre343oi9

Comment: Where is your mapping code?

Comment: Pls post your code

Comment: I think the question is  clear now. Or not ?

Comment: Your question is not clear and your code example is incomplete. Provide an executable example together with the output or error message. The most possible reason for your issue is that the structure of your Java classes do not match the structure of the JSON document. But debugging it  is impossible without having an executable program.

Comment: The problem is caused (for me) because of how jsonschema2pojo generated the Java fields to hold coordinates arrays. There are 3 coordinates structures in your sample JSON: (a) `"coordinates": [...]`, (b) `"coordinates": [ [...] ]`, and (c) `"coordinates": [ [ [...] ] ]`. As a test/hack, I forced the JSON to only use (b), and I adjusted the `Geometry` class's `coordinates` field to match. The data parsed without error after that.  I don't have an elegant solution.